# How to add a default value to checkout shipping postcode in magento 2

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.2, shipping-address

I am getting a zip code from the user when customer visit the website first time and saved the zip code using cookie.

I want to automatically set the zip code value saved in the cookie to checkout page shipping address **postcode** field.

How can i achieve this task.Please help me.**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

To archive this, you can fallback from your theme to `Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data.js` and change the function `initData` to add your default postcode value, as you can see here:

```
    /**
     * @return {*}
     */
    initData = function () {
        return {
            'selectedShippingAddress': null, //Selected shipping address pulled from persistence storage
            'shippingAddressFromData': {
                postcode: window.defaultCustomerZipCode
            }, //Shipping address pulled from persistence storage
            'newCustomerShippingAddress': null, //Shipping address pulled from persistence storage for customer
            'selectedShippingRate': null, //Shipping rate pulled from persistence storage
            'selectedPaymentMethod': null, //Payment method pulled from persistence storage
            'selectedBillingAddress': null, //Selected billing address pulled from persistence storage
            'billingAddressFromData': null, //Billing address pulled from persistence storage
            'newCustomerBillingAddress': null //Billing address pulled from persistence storage for new customer
        };
    },
```

In this case, I'm taking the value from a custom block and putting there as a default value this way:

Create a layout file `checkout_index_index.xml` in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block as="zipcode" class="Ziru\CustomerZipCode\Block\ZipCode" name="zipcode" template="Ziru_CustomerZipCode::zipcode.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

An then in the `.phtml` file you can call your block and add the value to the `window` object.

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Ziru\CustomerZipCode\Block\ZipCode
 */
?>
<div id="zip-code-details">
    <script>
        window.defaultCustomerZipCode = "<?= $block->getDefaultCustomerZipCode() ?>"
    </script>
</div>
```

**To take a way** Magento will apply any value in

```
'shippingAddressFromData': {
   postcode: window.defaultCustomerZipCode
 },
```

So feel free to have your value there following any logic that you want. And also, Magento will save `postcode` in the session as soon as the user changes this value. It means when the page gets refreshed the last value will be applied.

Lemme know if you could archive your challenger o/

Comment: thank you for your valuable time, I will try your solution and comeback.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put this in extentended js Theme\Magento_Checkout\web\js\checkout-data.js but it is not working

```
/**
     * @return {*}
     */
    initData = function () {
        return {
            'selectedShippingAddress': null, //Selected shipping address pulled from persistence storage
            'shippingAddressFromData': {
                postcode: '22522'
            }, //Shipping address pulled from persistence storage
            'newCustomerShippingAddress': null, //Shipping address pulled from persistence storage for customer
            'selectedShippingRate': null, //Shipping rate pulled from persistence storage
            'selectedPaymentMethod': null, //Payment method pulled from persistence storage
            'selectedBillingAddress': null, //Selected billing address pulled from persistence storage
            'billingAddressFromData': null, //Billing address pulled from persistence storage
            'newCustomerBillingAddress': null //Billing address pulled from persistence storage for new customer
        };
    }
```

Throws error like

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedPaymentMethod' of undefined

AND

[2021-03-10 08:05:51] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email" component.