# How can I set default zip code for checkout page and refresh shipping methods?

Tags: php, magento2.4.2

I created module for set default zip code in checkout page by this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/293818/102895. It's work - the ZIP code is set when the page loads by this plugin.

But shipping methods not refresh. How can I set default zip code and refresh shipping methods in checkout page during load page?

Comment: please explain little bit more how you want to refresh shipping methods on pagelaod?

Comment: I want the checkout page to load with the default zip code value that I set using the plugin, and that other services that require a zip code are loaded along with free standard delivery

Comment: try to add zipcode in shipping address when page loads it will automatically used for shipping method loads

Comment: I'm new to Magento, how can I do this?

Comment: I tried set zipcode by this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332491/102895 in JS, but isn't working for me

Comment: try my answer and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 1):

try this, Update LayoutProcessor.php

> app\code\Ketan\Module\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Ketan\Module\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $postcode = 369856;
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

        // Update the shipping address with the custom zip code
        $shippingAddress->setPostcode($postcode);

        $quote->save();
        /*================Start For Shipping Address ===========*/

        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;

        }

        /*================End For Shipping Address ===========*/




        /*================Start For Billing Address ===========*/
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list'])) {
            $paymentsList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

            foreach ($paymentsList as $paymentCode => $payment) {
                if(strpos($paymentCode, '-form') === false) {
                    continue;
                }
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;
            }
        }
         if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children'])){


            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;

        }

        /*================End For Billing Address ===========*/
        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

Comment: Checkout page loads with zip code, but I see only one shipping method - https://imgur.com/a/suiKa4u, but if I change zip code field manually - shipping methods refresh and a have two items

Comment: did you install any third party module?

Comment: No, checkout module used from Magento. The initial task is to hide the free shipping method and activated another shipping method instead. I'm trying to do this by specifying the default zip code and then influencing the choice of delivery via JS. Maybe there is an easier way to hide the free shipping method when loading the default shipping page and choose another one, knowing its carrierCode and methodCode?

Comment: you want to hide freeshipping based on conditions? i am unable to understand what you are trying to achive?

Comment: I want hide free shipping method during load checkout page and select other shipping method

Comment: you want to hide shipping for always or it will show up based on condition and which other shipping method you want to select??

Comment: No conditions, I want to hide it forever

Comment: disable it from admin